# What use cases are there in JavaScript for Sparse Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What possible programming use could you have where a sparse array would be better than an (regular) object?

By sparse array I mean one where:

```
arr = [];                             //Initialize
arr[0] = 'W';
arr[1] = 'T';
arr[3] = 'F';

console.log(arr[0] !== undefined)    //true
console.log(arr[1] !== undefined)    //true
console.log(arr[2] === undefined)    //true
console.log(arr[3] !== undefined)    //true
```

Or more formally:

```
An object, O, is said to be sparse if the following algorithm returns true:

1. Let len be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument 
"length".

2. For each integer i in the range 0≤i<ToUint32(len)
    a. Let elem be the result of calling the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method of O     
    with argument ToString(i).

    b. If elem is undefined, return true.

3. Return false.
```

[ECMA 262 5.1 - 15.4 Array Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

Moreover, the ECMA 262 5.1 Standard further defines `length` specifically as:

> The length property of this Array object is a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every deletable property whose name is an array index.

So the example above, `arr.length === 4` despite there only being three elements defined.

In fact, according to the standard, any `Number` greater than `3` is a valid `length` for `arr`, including `Math.PI`.

Consequently, does this mean that no one should use:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    //Cannot trust arr[i] exists
```

and instead it would be more appropriate to use

```
for(key in arr)
    //Always exists
```

I've never encountered an intentional one in the wild, and really only began thinking about it while reading an odd Q&A here, and now I'm a little unsettled.

I've long known that there's not a neat way to remove an element from an `Array`, but now I'm even more confused as to why you would intentionally leave a hole, let alone define a standard where length can be any number greater than the last defined element.

If I wanted random key value pairs, I'd use an `Object`. If I want to be able to cleanly iterate, I use an `Array`. Am I missing something?

Note, I'm looking for a specific use case, or a class of generalized use cases not a reference to the standards, or an opinion. I know it's allowed, and I already have an opinion. :)

To add a test or see some of the ones I've seen where the Array standard works in unexpected ways, check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtLvM/)

Sorry if this is a bit abstract. Been thinking about it all night.

Comment: The runtime can optimize "full" or semi-full portions of a sparse numerically-indexed array with real memory-based arrays. For arrays with length less than some threshold, it can *always* use a memory-based array no matter how sparse. Access, updates, etc will be a lot faster than via a hash.

Comment: Interesting question, but seriously: you need to find something to *do* on your nights... ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy. That's the sort of stuff I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that in a plain object there is absolutely no guarantee that you'll be able to iterate over the keys in any particular order.  The runtime is free to present the keys in any order it wants to, and it doesn't even have to be consistent.

Comment: @Pointy while that's technically true, I've always gotten the keys back in alphabetical order. In theory the implementation is free to set the length to PI according to the standard, but I've never seen that either. :)

Comment: @DavidThomas... I know. :)

Comment: you actually can iterate with a `for` loop, just wrap everything inside `if(i in arr){}`, or use `if(!(i in arr)){continue;}`

Comment: Conclusion: not everything defined in EcmaScript is reasonable and/or usable in practice. ;)

Comment: @JasonNichols In alphabetical order?!?! I have no recollection of any major browser with that behavior. I just tried `for (x in {b:1,a:2}) console.log(x);` in FF, Chrome, IE and Opera and all return it as "b, a", in the order they are defined, not in alphabetical order.

Comment: @JasonNichols [it's trivial to demonstrate otherwise.](http://jsfiddle.net/LbMTd/2/)

Comment: I stand corrected. I don't know why I remember always seeing them that way, but you guys are right.

Comment: The most important reason that comes to mind is the case when you create a new array with : var arr = new Array(initialLength); In this case, the array is at the same time 'empty' (all slots are undefined), and has a length of initiaLength . At least for this case, scarse array must be handled.

Comment: excellent point, @GameAlchemist. I always just create arrays with `var arr = []` and `push` to them, specifically to avoid falling into these kinds of traps.

Answer (score 3):

One possible use-case for sparse arrays that I've come across in real usage is for a heat-map.

Start with your map being an empty array of X × Y elements. Load your data, and populate it into the map by incrementing the array elements at the relevant co-ords.

Another similar example might be a battleship game, where boats are placed into an empty grid  by populating the array elements at the appropriate co-ordinates.

That's not to say this is this only way to do this, or even the best way -- both examples can quite easily be achieved without using a sparse array -- but the question was asking for use cases, so there you go.

Comment: I just don't know why you'd allocate memory to 100 spaces, when you only have 17 data points (assuming a 10x10 battleship grid, with the standard (5,4,3,3,2) ships). It seems so inefficient. The heat map example I get a bit more, it's likely to be less sparse, and you wouldn't have a trivial number of points to track.

Comment: yeah. as I say: use cases, yes... but not necessarily *good* use cases.  :)

Comment: "It seems so inefficient"... mmmm... using 800 bytes ( 100 X 4 bytes X 2 players) to handle a battleship game is just fine. Optimizing this would just be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

implementing the mathematical idea of 'sparse array' with JavaScript plain object (`{}`):

```js
source={}
source[1000000] = 1; source[2000000]=2; source[3000000]=3
start = new Date();
target = (function(){
  var ret = {};
  Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key){
    ret[key] = source[key]*source[key]
  });
  return ret
})();
end = new Date();
document.getElementById('runtime').textContent = end - start;
document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(target);
```

```html
........................ result ..........................
<div id="result"></div>
...................... run time ..........................
<div id="runtime"></div>
```

implementing the mathematical idea of 'sparse array' with JavaScript array (`[]`):

```js
source=[]
source[1000000] = 1; source[2000000]=2; source[3000000]=3
start = new Date();
target = source.map(function(u){ return u*u; });
end = new Date();
document.getElementById('runtime').textContent = end - start;
//document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(target);
console.log(target)
```

```html
........................ result ..........................
<div id="result">see console</div>
...................... run time ..........................
<div id="runtime"></div>
```

The runtime is show to be zero in the first snippet (below what can be properly measured unless you run it repeatedly). In the 2nd snippet the runtime is about 100 milliseconds on my machine.

Would you like to "pay" for a little less typing with such differences in runtime? And if you don't do the things that have this horrible runtime (do you know what they are??) what remains then of the saved typing? the answer to the last question is: nothing.

`{}` is the correct choice. `[]` is the *wrong* choice. IMHO.

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480871/foreach-vs-object-keys-foreach-performance-on-sparse-arrays)