# .forEach vs Object.keys().forEach performance on sparse arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, foreach, v8

Tell me if I'm wrong: `array.forEach(callbackFunction)` is suited for sparse arrays. It executes `callbackFunction` not for each index between zero and the array length, but only for the keys which are actually `in`  the array. And (tell me if I'm wrong) those keys are exactly what `Object.keys(array)` will give me. Hence (tell me *why* I'm wrong) it shouldn't make a difference if the `.forEach` method is called on `array` itself or on `Object.keys(array)`. So, why on earth is there this performance difference - as if, in one case, a giant pointless loop from zero to length would be executed, but not in the other case.

Snippet showing performance difference:

```js
function doNothing(){}
CONSOLE = document.getElementById('console');

arr = [];
arr[49888999] = 42;

start = performance.now();
arr.forEach(doNothing);
duration1 = performance.now() - start;

start = performance.now();
Object.keys(arr).forEach(doNothing);
duration2 = performance.now() - start;

CONSOLE.textContent = [duration1, duration2].join('\n');
```

```html
<pre id='console'></pre>
```

Snippet showing that the callback function **IS CALLED ONLY ONCE** in **BOTH** cases

```js
console1 = document.getElementById('console1');
console2 = document.getElementById('console2');
function doNothingVerbose1(){
  console1.textContent = 1 + (+console1.textContent);
}
function doNothingVerbose2(){
  console2.textContent = 1 + (+console2.textContent);
}

arr = [];
arr[49888999] = 42;

start = performance.now();
arr.forEach(doNothingVerbose1);
duration1 = performance.now() - start;

start = performance.now();
Object.keys(arr).forEach(doNothingVerbose2);
duration2 = performance.now() - start;

console.log(duration1, duration2);
```

```html
~~~~~ 1 ~~~~~
<pre id='console1'>0</pre>
~~~~~ 2 ~~~~~
<pre id='console2'>0</pre>
```

**UPDATE**

I just did a test to find out whether or not the above `arr=[];arr[49888999]=42;` is an actual sparse array, i.e. has much less memory footprint compared to doing `arr=new Array(49889000)`. And yes, that is the case. Doing this hundreds of times in a loop, the sparse version takes a couple of seconds but doesn't crash, but the `new Array(50 million)` version crashes the fiddle. So if it's not stored as a 'normal C++ array' in the engine then the engine must "have" `Object.keys` of the array, so why doesn't the engine make efficient use of it? I might have a too simplistic view of what a JS engine has to do; is it wrong to say that the engine must "have" `Object.keys` because it "has" a *sparse* array implementation backing our variable `arr` in some fashion? Maybe someone actually working on a browser/JS engine can shed some light here.

[above test on jsperf](https://jsperf.com/array-foreach-performance/1)

Comment: This is an implementation detail of the JS engine. There are several different JS engines in use depending on the environment, which use different optimization strategies, so there’s no universal answer to your question. I should note though that just because the callback isn’t invoked for an empty index doesn’t mean the engine doesn’t iterate over it. It has to somehow determine if it’s empty or not, after all.

Comment: @Lennholm: you're absolutely right linking this to the JS engine. That's why I added the v8 tag, thanks.

Comment: forEach still has to iterate over all numeric values from 0 to .length. For instance if you did `Object.defineProperty( arr, '42', { enumerable: false } )`, it should still pass over this non-enumerable `42` index, and if you did `arr["foo"] = bar`, it should  ignore this `foo` property.

Comment: @Kaiido: that sounds interesting. So you're saying, it possible that what `.forEach` loops over can be different from what `Object.keys` gives? I would love to see a fiddle for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well just `a = []; a.foo = "bar";` will do.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mathheadinclouds/vLpmch81/

fiddle for what @Kaiido just said.

Comment: @Kaiido, OK then, is it true that `Object.keys` will always give a superset of what `.forEach` will loop over? And, then, couldn't I just use `Object.keys(...).filter()` to boil down the keys to the "actual" ones? The filter function checking for the key being numerical, plus maybe other stuff (the esoteric enumerable: false thing you mentioned which I have never used in >20 years of JS, for example). You definitely got a point, but I still do not see why `.forEach` *HAS TO* loop over all those entries. "Has to" is a strong word, you know.

Comment: I already gave such an example too: `Object.defineProperty( arr, '42', { enumerable: false } )` https://jsfiddle.net/burt241f/

Comment: ah, right, now I see. The "foo" thing shows how Object.keys can give more, and the defineProperty thing shows how Object.keys can give less. So the defineProperty thing would make the big loop possibly necessary (not the foo thing, because we can use filter there, as I mentioned). I say "possibly", because, what do I know, maybe there is a method with which you can get all the stuff for which "defineProperty" has been called in one array.

Comment: @Kaiido: just trying to imagine what it is like to be a JS engine programmer, and what it would involve writing the implementation of `.forEach`. It's all very interesting what you're saying but it remains that the engine, due to having some implementation of a sparse array at it's disposal should not have to run this giant loop. It is **extremely** counter intuitive to me that such a loop would be necessary. This is strictly from the engine point of view.  I'm talking about the *engine* finding a way not to have to do the big loop, not some JS lib. I probably should shut up, not beingEnginDev

Comment: Sure they could have optimizations running on to make this case faster, but given how rare sparse arrays are compared to full ones, if having this optimization in place means slower iteration or value setting for all "normal" arrays, or bigger objects to store in memory, I can see how an implementer won't be willing to do this.

Comment: @mathheadinclouds have you read [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach)?

Comment: Using `Object.keys()` on an array seems like an anti-pattern to me. I would probably use a plain object instead of a sparse array if I found myself in this scenario.

Comment: @Lennholm: LOL, I just answered my own question (before your comment, but apparently, you didn't see it) with exactly the same thought. So we agree!

Comment: @MarkMeyer: I suffer from severe TL;DRobia. So no. But thanks for the link.

Comment: @Lennholm: The anti-pattern is not the usage of `Object.keys()`. It's to use `Array` at all. If you have such huge gaps, `Array` is simply the wrong choice. But not using `Object.keys()` won't make the error go away. On the contrary. It's the hacky fix which makes the error less bad. So yes. Plain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <s>as if</s> *because*, in one case, a giant pointless loop from zero to length <s>would be</s> *is* executed, but not in the other case.

---

According to the [ECMA documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18):

1. The `.forEach` method will loop through all array elements by its `.length` property.
2. The callback passed to `.forEach` will only be invoked if an element is not empty.

To demonstrate this you can simply do:

```js
function doNothing(){}
let perf;


console.log('Array with 50 million length and 1 non-empty element:');
const a = [];
a[49999999] = 'a';
console.log('a.length:', a.length);

perf = performance.now();
a.forEach(doNothing);
console.log('a:', performance.now() - perf);
console.log('');


console.log('Array with 0 length:');
const b = [];
b.foo = 'a';
console.log('b.length:', b.length);

perf = performance.now();
b.forEach(doNothing);
console.log('b:', performance.now() - perf);
console.log('');


console.log('Array with 50 million length and 0 non-empty element:');
const c = [];
c.length = 50000000;
console.log('c.length:', c.length);

perf = performance.now();
c.forEach(doNothing);
console.log('c:', performance.now() - perf);
```

Comment: The engine probably *could* add a fast path for that case, but simply hasn't gotten around to it yet because there were more urgent issues to work on. The Array.prototype.forEach implementation is complicated enough as it is...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, ok, ok - so it's just one of those things one has to live with; I didn't want to hear that, but that *is* the right answer.

I'm going to continue to not read specs, and be bewildered at times. No, I'm not recommending that behavior, it's just the way I roll. Trying it out on the console just makes more sense to me, it's definitely more fun, while specs tend to make me fall asleep. Thankfully, people are different, and not everybody is like that.

Maybe a more interesting question is how to deal with the phenomenon in practice. If, for example, I have to deal with a 'sparse Array' as in "2 items of product 51472 and 1 item of product 81369", I'll use an *object* (`{}`) with keys 51472 and 81369, and *not* an array (`[]`).

Making it an array just because all keys happen to be non-negative integers is <s>a bad idea</s> **the worst idea of the last 10 thousand years** - because you then have `.forEach`, which is a **FALSE FRIEND**

2 related questions:

[Why are we allowed to create sparse arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526520/why-are-we-allowed-to-create-sparse-arrays-in-javascript)

[What use cases are there in JavaScript for Sparse Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126593/what-use-cases-are-there-in-javascript-for-sparse-arrays)